# Java: read from binary file, send bytes over socket

Tags: java, sockets, binary-data

This should be easy, but I can't get my head around it right now. I wanna send some bytes over a socket, like

```
Socket s = new Socket("localhost", TCP_SERVER_PORT);
DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream()));

DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()));

for (int j=0; j<40; j++) {
  dos.writeByte(0);
}
```

That works, but now I dont want to  writeByte to the Outputstream, but read from a binary file, then write it out. I know(?) I need a FileInputStream to read from, I just can't figure out hot to construct the whole thing.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html explains how to create FileInputStream from a file name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void transfer(final File f, final String host, final int port) throws IOException {
    final Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
    final BufferedOutputStream outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    final BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    for (int read = inStream.read(buffer); read >= 0; read = inStream.read(buffer))
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
    inStream.close();
    outStream.close();
}
```

This would be the naive approach without proper exception handling - in a real-world setting you'd have to make sure to close the streams if an error occurs.

You might want to check out the Channel classes as well as an alternative to streams. FileChannel instances, for example, provide the transferTo(...) method that may be a lot more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, it works and really helps me out, that buffer array thing is new to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", TCP_SERVER_PORT);

        String fileName = "....";
```

create a FileInputStream using a fileName

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
```

create a FileInputStream File Object

```
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
```

to read from the file

```
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
        s.getOutputStream()));
```

reading from it byte after byte

```
    int element;
    while((element = fis.read()) !=1)
    {
        dos.write(element);
    }
```

or reading from it buffer wise

```
byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[1024]; // buffer

    while(fis.read(byteBuffer)!= -1)
    {
        dos.write(byteBuffer);
    }

    dos.close();
    fis.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

read a byte from the input and write the same byte to the output

or with a byte buffer it like this:

```
inputStream fis=new fileInputStream(file);
byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
int read;
while((read=fis.read(buff))>=0){
    dos.write(buff,0,read);
}
```

note that you don't need to use the DataStreams for this